# Error output with karma instanbul coverage reports

Tags: karma-runner, istanbul

I'm trying to generate coverage reports and I'm running into an issue. I get a `Error: Unable to lookup source` error...

[image]

I don't understand why it is looking for the `?[hash]` in the file name, if there a way to remove this?

My grunt-karma config:

```
  var webpack = {
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src|vue-router\//,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['es2015', { 'modules': false }]
          ],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          postLoaders: {
            js: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader?esModules=true'
          }
        }
      }, {
        include: /\.json$/,
        loaders: ['json-loader']
      }, {
        enforce: 'post',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src|vue-router\/|test\//,
        loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        query: {
          debug: true,
          preserveComments: true,
          esModules: true
        }
      }]
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules'],
      alias: {vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'}
    }
  };

karma: {
  unit: {
    options: {
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      singleRun: true,
      colors: true,
      browsers: ['Chrome'],
      phantomjsLauncher: {
        exitOnResourceError: true
      },
      reporters: ['spec', 'coverage-istanbul'],
      files: [
        { pattern: 'test/unit/**/*-spec.js', watched: false }
      ],
      preprocessors: {
        'test/unit/**/*-spec.js': ['webpack']
      },
      webpack: {
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        module: webpack.module,
        resolve: webpack.resolve
      },
      webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true,
        stats: 'errors-only'
      },
      coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        dir: './build/reports/unit',
        reports: [ 'text-summary', 'html' ],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        'report-options': {
          html: {
            verbose: true,
            subdir: 'html'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    specReporter: {
      suppressSkipped: false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `devtool: 'eval-source-map'`